# SQL Server login per application user

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am looking for different ways to uniquely identify an application user in SQL Server 2008.

To give some back ground to the issue:
The ASP.NET 4 web application I work with uses an SQL Server 2008 database, there is one SQL Server login and DB User for all connections from the application to database.

We are developing a reporting solution using Crystal Reports where users can write and execute their own reports through the application. The crystal reports can only return data from Views. Each application user will have their own unique login to the server.
The View then uses SELECT SYSTEM_USER() to find the logged in user and restrict data returned from the view.

- Is it bad practice to create a distinct login and DB user for each application user? This would mean > 1000 users per DB, across up to 80 databases (Creation of 
  each log in would be handled through T-SQL, not manually)
- What other ways can the user be identified in the View in the DB?
- We looked at altering the connection string to include the user id in the Workstation ID, we can use SELECT HOST_NAME() to get the ID, but this seems like abuse of the Workstation ID.

Any other suggestions about how the user can be uniquely identified would be appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Windows Authentication as apposed to SQL Authentication?  That would at least reduce the number of logins & users that would need to be managed.

Comment: Yes that's a good idea, the problem we have is the users are not on the network. They are just accessing the web site through an id/pwd set up in the web application. Ideally we should be using Windows Authentication anyway for better security but I don't think it's workable in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Y can use external database,file or other resource  to store user access to any data when u use msql 2008.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

That give y change to not mix data with audit elements for performance and security reasons.
Use profiler on your sql server and in profiler is information about ( aplication , user , and host ). So that kind of information y can easy get by audit or from custom trigger on certain database objects.

Your aplication can also have own user table and share the same connection string too all users or give users with windows auth type only public privilege. And use in stored procedures run as command ( run as another user in db). 
So y can log any user and give them minimal rights.

Its my firs post here and I actually learning English lol.

Answer (score 0):

There were two solutions that we came up with:

1. Before the Crystal report is executed, in .Net we can extract the SQL the report (and sub report) will generate, execute the SQL and put the results in a dataset and generate the report from the dataset. The advantage of this is that because we have the SQL, before the SQL executes, we can supply user information to the SQL server session that can be used to identify the user when the SQL is executing.
2. Have a limited number of SQL Server user logins which can be dynamically assigned to application users. We will have a table which will map the SQL Server Login to an application user just before they run a Crystal report. When they query has finished executing the Login is released. Obviously this means that at busy times we may run out of Logins, but more can be added depending on usage.